# Changing HTML Checkbox list into select dropdown list with PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a html/php form that allows an array of data to be displayed in a drop/selection menu. How would i turn this into one?

```
<?php

$OptionID   =   1;

foreach( $this->setRoleOptions as $RoleID => $RoleName ) :

    echo '<div align="center">';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" style="width: 30px;" name="RoleID" value="'. $RoleID .'" ';

    if ( $OptionID == 1 ) :

        echo ' CHECKED ';

    endif;

    echo '/>&nbsp;'. $RoleName;
    echo '</div>';

    ++$OptionID; 

endforeach;

?>
```

I have tried the below code which gets the array but once the option is selected, nothing happens.

```
<?php
$OptionID = array("Administrative", "Operations 1", "Operations 2");
?>

<select>
    <?php foreach ($this->setRoleOptions as $RoleID => $RoleName): ?>
    <option name="RoleID" value="<?php echo $RoleID; ?>"<?php if ($row['RoleID'] == $OptionID): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
        <?php echo $RoleName;?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you mean the markup? currently its in checkbox form, then just change the markup into `select` dropdown menu. `<select>`

Comment: Do i need to add the echo select above where the input line is?

Comment: 1. The `name=RoleID` should be inside `<select>` tag 2. I see you miss the `</select>` end tag, is that a copy-paste mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To translate the checkboxes that you have currently, just create a simple `<select>` markup using the same data that you have.

Here's the idea:

```
<?php $OptionID = array("Administrative", "Operations 1", "Operations 2"); ?>

<select name="RoleID">
    <?php foreach ($this->setRoleOptions as $RoleID => $RoleName): ?>
    <option 
        value="<?php echo $RoleID; ?>" 
        <?php echo in_array($RoleID, $OptionID) ? 'selected: ''; ?>
    >
        <?php echo $RoleName; ?>
    </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

The `name` attribute should be on the `select` tag itself. The `value` attributes should be on the `option` tags.

And since on each iteration, you'd want to check whether the current `$RoleID` is inside the `$OptionID` which is an array, it would be better to use the built in function `in_array()` instead.

Comment: Awesome it works which means i was close but yet so far. Thank you

Comment: @DashawnThompson yep, needed a few alterations here and there but the idea is there. glad this one helped

Comment: @mickmackusa sure, its somewhat related to what the OP is trying to check with the empty values, i do agree though that `int (0)` would yield a false positive

Answer (score 0):

the `select` tab should have a name, while option doesn't.